# Meteor method cannot read property "quantity" undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I'm getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined" when running this meteor method.

Frontend call:

```
Template.listingPage.events({
"submit #add-to-cart": function(e,t){
    e.preventDefault();
    var quantity = parseInt($("#spinner-01").val());
    var listingId = t.data._id;

    if(!Session.get("cartId")){
            var id = Carts.insert({ line_items: []});
            Session.set("cartId", id);
    }
    var cartId = Session.get("cartId");


    Meteor.call("addToCart", (quantity, listingId, cartId), function(err, res){
        if(err){
            toastr.error(err.reason, "Error");
        } else{
            toastr.success("Added to cart", "Success");
        }
    });

}
});
```

Method ( in collection folder ):

```
Meteor.methods({
addToCart: function(quantity, listingId, cartId){
    var listing = Listings.findOne(listingId);

    if(quantity > listing.quantity)
        throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'You cannot add that many to your cart');

    var lineItem = LineItems.find({ cartId: cartId, listingId: listingId });
    if(lineItem){
        //in cart
        var cartQuantity = lineItem.quantity;
        if ( (cartQuantity + quantity) > listing.quantity)
            throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'You cannot add that many to your cart');


        LineItems.update({ cartId: Session.get("cartId"), listingId: listingId}, { $inc: { quantity: quantity}});
        toastr.success("Added to cart", "Success");

    } else{
        // not in cart
        lineItem = {
            cartId: cartId,
            listingId: listingId,
            quantity: quantity,
            imageId: listing.imageObj._id
        }
        LineItems.insert(lineItem);
        Carts.update(cartId, { $inc: { count: 1 }});
    }
}
});
```

Line 5 on the method is causing the error, it seems listing is undefined. Why is this the case when I am subscribed to the listing on the route that calls the method. Do I need to make it a server only method?

Comment: Could you post the subscription code as well?

Comment: fixed it by putting everything into an object and just passing that in as an argument rather than 3 arguements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the method

```
Meteor.call("addToCart", (quantity, listingId, cartId), function(err, res){
```

you shouldn't have the `(` `)` around `quantity, listingId, cartId`:

```
Meteor.call("addToCart", quantity, listingId, cartId, function(err, res){
```

When you write `f(a, (b, c, d), e)`, the `(b, c, d)` is actually the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which evaluates all its operands, then returns the last one. So this is the same as `f(a, d, e)`.